# Hadoop MapReduce environment variables

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am experimenting with Hadoop MapReuce environment variables.
My usecase is rather unusual, however it's not reason I am strugle.

My goal its to export environment variable on all my mappers and reducers. 
For that I am using `mapreduce.map.env` and `mapreduce.reduce.env` conf settings in the following way:

```
hadoop jar myJob.jar -Dmapreduce.map.env="A=foo"
```

This works great and indeed expose `A` on all my mappers.
In that point I will mention that `mapreduce.map.env` is really lack of documentation or usecase examples on the internet.

My problem is that my project runs MapReduce jobs by layers each layer can pass flags to the hadoop jar command while I don't control the upper layers.

Therefore I can run the following command:

```
hadoop jar -Dmapreduce.map.env="A=foo" -Dmapreduce.map.env="B=foo2"
```

To my best knowledge and experiments (do correct me if I wrong) this command will only expose "B=foo2" on my mapper environment.

I can't find anything on the net to overcome this problem.

IMPOTENT NOTE: Since I only know the env variable I want to expose on runtime(it's dynamic and can change) I can't add the env variables to the mapred-default/stie.xml

Comment: You can comma separate one argument. If you pass multiple, they do override each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @cricket_007 answer: You can comma separate one argument. If you pass multiple, they do override each other.

Worked fine